# SVN error: Can't set position pointer in file. There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When trying to do an SVN update I'm getting this error:

`Can't set position pointer in file.. There is not enough space on the disk.`

My C: drive isn't full on my Windows 8 machine and I've tried doing an SVN clean-up. I also did a disk cleanup on my temporary files and a reinstall of subversion. I'm having the same issue.

Screenshot:

[image: Update Failed Screenshot]

Comment: change temp path to a valid directory.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Where do I change the temp path at?

Comment: in windows settings. since vista the folder structure is changed and **C:\documents & settings** is no longer used. all user data are now store in **C:\Users\USERNAME**

Comment: @magicandre1981 I checked my environment variables and they are set correctly. I don't see where else I can change the temp path.

Comment: what is your temp path setting?

Comment: The environment variable?

Comment: I want to see the temp variables.

Comment: Where do I find those at? Can you give me the location?

Comment: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-edit-environment-variables-quickly-in-windows-8-1-and-windows-8/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132325/discussion-between-user2531854-and-magicandre1981).

Comment: path is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` for TMP and TEMP

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Mine is failing when looking for `C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp` but the path 
`C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp` does exist.

Comment: I just tried to update 4 working copies (on the same drive). 3 of them succeeded, one of them failed with that error. Which means it's not temp path related. Any other ideas what can cause this and how it can be fixed?